# Google contacts. GetPhoto

Tags: python, google-api, gdata

We want to import contacts photos from google API.

Following code was working for me.

```
for email, name, entry in feed:
    photo = client.GetPhoto(entry)
    if photo:
        fname = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.jpg'
        image_file = open(dname + '/' + fname, 'wb')
        image_file.write(photo)
        image_file.close()
        result[email] = '/media/import/%s/%s' % (dir, fname)
```

Now, for some reasons, we get in files atom feed copy. So method `GetPhoto` no working.

Any ideas, why it happened and what is current way to retrieve contacts photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is work around google API changes. Now we're using direct requests to API.

```
for email, name, entry in feed:
    photo_link = e.GetPhotoLink()
    if photo_link:
        request = http.request(
            'GET',
            photo_link.href,
            headers={
                'Authorization':'OAuth %s' % client.current_token.access_token
            }
        )

        if request.status == 200:
            photo = str(request.read())
            fname = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.jpg'
            image_file = open(dname + '/' + fname, 'wb')
            image_file.write(photo)
            image_file.close()
            result[email] = '/media/import/%s/%s' % (tid, fname) #str(photo.href) #
```